# Install parallel-ssh==1.9.1 Python 3.7.16 on Apple M1 Pro 14.2.1

Tags: python, installation, pip, apple-m1, parallel-ssh

I'm running into problems installing parallel-ssh==1.9.1 on my Python 3.7.16. When installing I get the following error:

```
Downloading zope.event-5.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: parallel-ssh, ssh2-python, zope.interface, cffi
  Building wheel for parallel-ssh (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for parallel-ssh: filename=parallel_ssh-1.9.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl size=81652 sha256=5442f141ec1584759d3b4df423a67d46a8921ebdb2561651e7c8ec696d0bb6a2
  Stored in directory: /Users/ekl/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/9b/83/e2/521569088dd75073ad11d33f1b604572725ca3d373d9a6f062
  Building wheel for ssh2-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: cmake: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/j1/5kv3krf177z_t3n2n5nyzhqm0000gp/T/pip-install-plbsxp0y/ssh2-python_bad6d8eb0c1e4527a569d49e92dcbc51/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
          build_ssh2()
        File "/private/var/folders/j1/5kv3krf177z_t3n2n5nyzhqm0000gp/T/pip-install-plbsxp0y/ssh2-python_bad6d8eb0c1e4527a569d49e92dcbc51/_setup_libssh2.py", line 38, in build_ssh2
          shell=True, env=os.environ)
        File "/Users/ekl/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake ../libssh2/libssh2 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON     -DENABLE_ZLIB_COMPRESSION=ON -DENABLE_CRYPT_NONE=ON     -DENABLE_MAC_NONE=ON -DCRYPTO_BACKEND=OpenSSL' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ssh2-python
  Running setup.py clean for ssh2-python
  Building wheel for zope.interface (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for zope.interface: filename=zope.interface-6.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl size=202524 sha256=d17e1d88242c6aaafb23486ac9291776378a26d096740168ebfabd96f621b092
  Stored in directory: /Users/ekl/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/69/d3/42/5f149ced569a4055b0ce71de34f0285ae7845bac7e0b72780e
  Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for cffi: filename=cffi-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_14_0_arm64.whl size=174663 sha256=43c782a6100770a0cfb0c72ed3c2e3af2ed306077153b2dd41dea950ac00eb98
  Stored in directory: /Users/ekl/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/04/6e/00/ce829dde11540887b1a7ce4905b5a63c36fa1d6ed8afeacf98
Successfully built parallel-ssh zope.interface cffi
Failed to build ssh2-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ssh2-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The use of this library is quite important for me, since work of several scripts that I use in my work depends on it.
I attribute the installation issues to the fact that I'm currently using a Macbook Pro with an Apple M1 Pro - I've already encountered problems installing earlier versions of Python because of this.

I also tried upgrade my pip and some other tools with 'python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel'. This fixed the previous errors during installation, but the error I indicated above did not.

**UPDATE**

@wombatonfire Thanks for you answer! I installed cmake as per the advice below and now I get the error:

```
  running build_ext
  building 'pssh.native._ssh2' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/pssh
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/pssh/native
  clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/ekl/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/ekl/anaconda3/include -arch arm64 -I/Users/ekl/anaconda3/include/python3.11 -c pssh/native/_ssh2.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-311/pssh/native/_ssh2.o -O3
  pssh/native/_ssh2.c:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
    #include "longintrepr.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for parallel-ssh
  Running setup.py clean for parallel-ssh
  Failed to build parallel-ssh
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for parallel-ssh, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This error seems very strange to me, since it mentions that I have Anaconda 3.11 installed - but now Python 3.7.12 is selected in my pyenv. I don't understand why the installation just doesn't happen for this version of Python.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem seems clear (but not the solution). It's strange, but now I can't assign the correct Python version through pyenv - I assign the version through

```
pyenv global 3.7.16
pyenv local 3.7.16
```

But when checking the version via **python3 --version**
I'm getting

```
Python 3.11.5
```

Comment: You should use a more recent version of this library, as they are shipping wheels so you won't have to build them yourself

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, I am forced to use exactly this old version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/sh: cmake: command not found` - this is the problem, `cmake` is required to build the wheel for `ssh2-python`, and you don't have it installed on your system.

You can install `cmake` with:

- MacPorts: `sudo port install cmake`
- Homebrew: `brew install --cask cmake`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But now I'm faced with another problem...

Comment: @KonradDeBete I understand your frustration with all these errors, but please keep in mind that a question on Stack Overflow is not a support chat. You should create separate questions for separate issues. If the answer helped you with your original error, please upvote it and accept it as a solution for the original issue. As for your problem with Python environments, yes, it seems you are installing in the wrong environment, but again, this is a matter for a separate question. Just don't forget to search for existing pyenv questions on SO first.

Comment: @KonradDeBete To add some details: you're dealing with, at least, 3 separate issues. Your original error - the one I tried to handle in my answer - is related to a missing `cmake`. Your second error from the update you posted seems to be related specifically to Python 3.11. If you search for "'longintrepr.h' file not found", you will find a similar question on SO with a possible solution to downgrade Python to 3.10. Though, in your case, it's irrelevant, since you don't really want to build the wheel for Python 3.11, but instead for Python 3.7 in a different environment.